# uint8_t values issues with vectors

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a 10 by 10 grid with uint8_t values. using some coordinates I am trying to place 255 values at those indexes. When I substitute 255 at those coordinates it works fine but as soon as I try to print out the values at those indexes it doesn't seem to be the values I wanted.

```
float grid_width = 10;
float grid_height = 10;
float grid_resolution = 0.05;
float rows = grid_width/grid_resolution;
float cols = grid_height/grid_resolution;

std::vector<std::vector<float>> landmarks = {{2,2},{8,8},{2,8},{8,2},{3,2},{3.5,2.1},{4.0,3.5},{4.5,2.0},{5.0,3.0}};
std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> grid(rows, std::vector<uint8_t>(cols, 0));

for(auto i: landmarks)
{
    for(auto m = i[0]-(grid_resolution*2) ; m <= i[0] +(grid_resolution*2) ; m=m+grid_resolution )
    {
        for(auto n = i[1]-(grid_resolution*2); n <= i[1]+(grid_resolution*2); n=n+grid_resolution)
        {
            int m_co = m/grid_resolution;
            int n_co = n/grid_resolution;
            grid[m_co][n_co] = 255;
            cout<<"m_co: "<< m_co <<" n_co:" << n_co <<endl;
            cout<<"grid[m_co][n_co]: "<< unsigned(grid[m_co][n_co])  <<endl; //check the printout over here for index values of 18,22 you will see 255 but when you try it outside the for loops those values are rest to 0
            
        }
        
    }
}

// for(auto m: grid)
// {
//     for(auto n: m)
//     {
//         cout<<unsigned(n)<<" ";
//     }
//     cout<<endl;
// }
cout<<unsigned(grid[18][18])<<endl; //expected 255 got 255
cout<<unsigned(grid[18][22])<<endl; //expected 255 got 0
cout<<unsigned(grid[22][22])<<endl; //expected 255 got 0
cout<<unsigned(grid[22][18])<<endl; //expected 255 got 0
cout<<unsigned(grid[17][17])<<endl; //expected 255 got 0
cout<<unsigned(grid[20][18])<<endl; //expected 255 got 255
```

So I am taking indexes using landmarks vector and trying to replace 0 from grid vector to 255 on the indexes of landmarks, but I also want to replace 0  on the indexes around that index.
like if 2,2 is my coordinate I want to replace 1,1 and 1,2 and 1,3 and 2,1 and 2,2, and 2,3 and 3,1 and 3,2 and 3,3 to 255 but I do not get 1,3 and 2,3 and 3,3 255 i get 0
this is just an example I am trying to achive

Comment: why would you allocate vectors using float variables for the sizes?

Comment: Can you make this into a [mcve] and explain the undesired behavior you're seeing, perhaps with an example of right and wrong? Consider casting to `unsigned int` instead of just `unsigned`.

Comment: I had edit above with comments on what was expected I what I received.

Comment: You can simulate it on your side too.

Comment: @QuickSilver We could, if you made a [mcve] that could be copy/pasted and compiled/run. Have you used a debugger to step through and verify things? If you're going to print things out you should print `m_co` and `n_co` directly and not do the math again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution. the old logic was too complex and not working with different resolutions. So I made a simpler one that does need to take care of rounding up issues.
first took each point and tried to go replace values index by index.

```
for(auto i: landmarks)
{
    for(int m = (i[0]/grid_resolution)-2; m <= (i[0]/grid_resolution)+2; m++)
    {
        for(int n = (i[1]/grid_resolution)-2; n <= (i[1]/grid_resolution)+2; n++)
        {
            grid[m][n] = 255;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the loop you are printing `n/grid_resolution`. When it prints `22`, it is actually 21.99999809265, but because the default precision of iostream is 6, it is rounded to 22. On the other hand, when you assign it to `int`, it is rounded down to `21`, so you actually store 255 in `grid[18][21]`.

Comment: that kind of makes sense and how can I fix it

Comment: used std::ceil and it worked but its doing over correcting

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that m/grid_resolution has type float, while m_co has type int:

```
int main()
{
    float grid_width = 10;
    float grid_height = 10;
    float grid_resolution = 0.1;
    float rows = grid_width/grid_resolution;
    float cols = grid_height/grid_resolution;
    cout.precision(5);
    
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> landmarks = {{2,2},{8,8},{2,8},{8,2},{3,2},{3.5,2.1},{4.0,3.5},{4.5,2.0},{5.0,3.0}};
    std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> grid(rows, std::vector<uint8_t>(cols, 0));
    
    for(auto i: landmarks)
    {
        for(auto m = i[0]-(grid_resolution*2) ; m <= i[0] +(grid_resolution*2) ; m=m+grid_resolution )
        {
            for(auto n = i[1]-(grid_resolution*2); n <= i[1]+(grid_resolution*2); n=n+grid_resolution)
            {
                int m_co = m/grid_resolution;
                int n_co = n/grid_resolution;
                grid[m_co][n_co] = 255;
                // Uncomment the following two lines for showing that are different
                //if (m_co != m/grid_resolution || n_co != n/grid_resolution)
                //    cout << "different" << endl;
                cout << "grid["<<m_co<<"]["<<n_co<<"]: "<< unsigned(grid[m_co][n_co]) << endl;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    // for(auto m: grid)
    // {
    //     for(auto n: m)
    //     {
    //         cout<<unsigned(n)<<" ";
    //     }
    //     cout<<endl;
    // }
    cout<<"grid[18][18]" << unsigned(grid[18][18])<<endl;
    cout<<"grid[18][22]" << unsigned(grid[18][22])<<endl;
    cout<<"grid[22][22]" << unsigned(grid[22][22])<<endl;
    cout<<"grid[22][18]" << unsigned(grid[22][18])<<endl;
    cout<<"grid[17][17]" << unsigned(grid[17][17])<<endl;
    cout<<"grid[20][18]" << unsigned(grid[20][18])<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you run that code, the right values of `m_co` and `n_co` will be printed.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I print inside for loop I get the right values but when I print outside for loop those values are back to 0

Comment: I tried changing it from int to float still see 0 for 18 and 22 outside for loop